# How do you prevent being lead astray when you're working on a problem that takes months/years?

Tags: soft-question, self-learning, problem-solving, education

Usually, when you're a student, the textbook/teacher has organized the structure of your education such that you are led on the right path. You are basically "taken by hand" to make sure that after a few years, you end up having learned the right things.

As a student, you might be led astray for a few hours or at most days, if you're working on a problem, but have not found the right approach. But then, either the next lecture begins, which directs you on the right path, or you can simply ask the teacher, or you simply look at the next problem in the textbook. **In general, it is therefore hard for a student to consistently take the wrong approach, without being corrected.**

However, when you are working on a frontier research problem, there is no one to hold your hand. **Potentially, you could spend months or years trying to solve a problem with the wrong approach.** (e.g. I'm not sure if this is a good example, since I don't know anything about it, but I read that "Erik Christopher Zeeman tried for 7 years to prove that one cannot untie a knot on a 4-sphere. Then one day he decided to try to prove the opposite, and succeeded in a few hours.")

---

My question is basically, What do you do (or what can we do) to **prevent this trap?** What can we do to **prevent spending months or years**

> 1. trying to solve a problem that doesn't have a solution.
> 2. trying the wrong approach to a problem.
> 3. working on a problem that turns out not to be of any value.
> 4. other possible ways of being led astray.

Comment: The only way to reliably avoid these traps is not to attempt any original work.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown, the only way to reliably not die in a car accident is to not partake in traffic. Yet there are still things we can do to prevent car accidents.

Comment: You can avoid 1 by working both simple and involved examples to convince yourself that what you're trying to prove is true.  Obviously not applicable to all fields.  Sometimes you can abstract a method of proof from your examples which helps you stay away from 2.  You can avoid 3 by being getting involved with the people in your research area, going to conferences, meeting people and then getting a sense of which problems are interesting.

Comment: When you are an active researcher you are still allowed and even encouraged to ask questions or ask someone to check your work. It's called collaboration, and the only price is having to share credit. Moreover, if you are working on a problem for years, you still have to publish papers / participate in conferences. Then anyone can check your work

Comment: Get a graduate advisor, or failing that, find other people to work with.